# Separate line in json file from Express node.js

Tags: node.js, json

I want to split lines in json file but I can't. Can anyone help with my code as below?

```
$('.searchResultsItem', html).each(function () {
            const text = $(this).find('a').attr('title')
            const url = $(this).find('a ').attr('href')
            articles.push({
                text,
                url
            })
        })
        res.json(articles)
```

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Azj0Z.jpg)

Comment: Split what lines? What JSON file? JSON is data; the *presentation* of that data is a separate issue.

Comment: It's worth noting that your JSON file doesn't seem to have any tags named "title" nor "href", only "text" and "url"

Comment: I want it to be one line below after text and url, I apologize for my explanation I'm not a developer.

Comment: You want what to be “one line below”?

Comment: After URL, one line break like json formatting. Like this https://i.imgur.com/mGJUwrm.png

Comment: Please actually say how/where you’re trying to view the data. If it’s in HTML then use `JSON.stringify(articles, null, 2)` and put in  a `<pre>` tag. If it’s in a file you *could* do the same, but could also treat it like the data it is and use a tool like `jq` or an editor to format it. It’s not clear what you’re actually *doing*.

Comment: localhost:8000 port /results is it HTML file? I don't know. I'm trying to show local machine